# SBT 0.13.8 what does the SettingKey.~= method do

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13

The SettingKey.~= method is used to exclude dependencies from libraryDependencies (see [play 2.3.8 sbt excluding logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534528/play-2-3-8-sbt-excluding-logback/41626728#41626728)), but trying to find out what it does is hard as:

1. There is no documentation about this function at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.12/api/index.html#sbt.SettingKey,
2. It cannot be searched using Google as it uses symbols in the method name and
3. Examination of the SBT source code (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/settings/src/main/scala/sbt/Structure.scala#L47) does not provide an obvious answer.

Can anyone shed light on what this does?

Comment: "It cannot be searched using Google as it uses symbols in the method name" - just to say that isn't true as I found this question in exactly this way. Maybe Google's gotten a bit smarter about including squiggles in queries.

Answer (score 10):

```
someScopedKey ~= f
```

is equivalent to

```
someScopedKey := f(someScopedKey.value)
```

In other words, it transforms the previous value of the setting/task with a given function. That's literally all there is to know about it.

Comment: Would I be correct to describe it as a mapping operation?

Comment: I would call it a transformation. It certainly does not follow the (loosely speaking) monadic meaning of `map` as understood in Scala.

Comment: Hi @sjrd just curious, where was this documented in sbt documentation?